# Razor code leaking onto the Contacts page

Tags: bug, status-completed, contact-form

The [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact) page:

[image]

The first blue link is `https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=@Current.Referrer.UrlEncode()`.

Comment: This is already in progress to fix. Hopefully done on Monday. Thanks for bringing it to our attention!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will be fixed with the next prod deploy. Thanks for the report!